# Upload / Store files from one laravel app to another laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a situation where i need to build Rest APIs for the iOS and other apps using **Laravel passport**. And i also have a web app. this web app and API app located on different servers. They are sharing same database and hence i need to share storage as well. So i would like to upload files through API to the web apps storage folder.

I don't want to use any external storage service.

do i need to create some custom drive for this?
something like -

```
's3' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
    'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
],
```

How do i accomplish this?
Need guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own disk based on the local driver. For example, add the following to your `disks` array in `filesystems.php`.

```php
'mystoragedisk' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => '/path/to/storage/on/server',
]
```

You could then either change the default storage disk to your new one, or call the `disk` method when storing or retrieving files.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. i tried this it gives this error. - `"message": "Impossible to create the root directory `

Comment: Depending on your root directory, it sounds like a permissions issue.

Comment: It's likely to be something non code related. It depends on what type of server you are running it on, whether it is using Apache/NGINX, what user/group the PHP-FPM process is running as. Unfortunately without information about what the application is being run on there isn't a lot that we can help with.

Comment: Actually server is ubuntu running apache2

Comment: actually when i create web app on that server i give these permissions 

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/wts 

sudo find /var/www/wts -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; 

sudo find /var/www/wts -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache

sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache`

Comment: what is the directory the web app is running on and what is the directory the web app has set the location to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193707/discussion-between-truecode-and-george-hanson).